# Synonyms for "freak show" or idioms for a "working awkwardness"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

What are other expressions that describe some prepared, working awkwardness, that's is worth to show because it does work and/or is interesting, and even maybe solves some problems?

Example of such mechanisms are [esoteric programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language). One of them is for sure Whitespace:

> Whitespace uses only whitespace characters (space, tab, and return),
>   ignoring all other characters. This is the reverse of many traditional
>   languages, which do not distinguish between different whitespace
>   characters, treating tab and space the same. It also allows Whitespace
>   programs to be hidden in the source code of programs in languages like
>   C.

Comment: Could you give some examples, and how you would use it?

Comment: Maybe it's a _curiosity_?

Comment: @Barmar: that's a valid answer

Comment: I don't see how "freak show" (in the title) fits with the question. Synonyms for "freak show" would not be a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: that's the problem, the physic reality that the expressions cover. Consider the esoteric programming language B** f**. It works, is enough interesting to present it, however even its author considered it being a "freak show". PS. I now see your answer, interesting point about the Schrodinger's cat.

Comment: PS. What I meant about the problem being covered is a phenomenon that induces contradict judgements because of the reasons like awkwardness. So the expressions can be also more or less opposite. Didn't thought about positive expressions much in the beginning because they tend to be based on inprecise, emotional description like "miracle" or "astonishing", etc. that loses the contradict quality.

Comment: Are you an English Language Learner?  If so, please post questions to http://ell.stackexchange.com. It is there that we provide answers to questions from English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These could generally be described as *theoretical exercises* (or *intellectual exercises*).  Closely related is [*thought experiments*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment).

For example, the original [Turing Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) itself, if considered the basis of a programming language, can seem just as odd and funny as many of the deliberately odd-and-funny esoteric programming languages.  In fact, the Turing Machine is the basis of a class of [esolang](https://www.google.com/search?q=esolang) called [turing tarpits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit).  Also, [Bloop and Floop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlooP_and_FlooP) are prepared languages to demonstrate the difference between non Turing-complete and Turing-complete langauges.

Obscure and weird-yet-useful constructs are often the basis for [recreational mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_mathematics).  David Singmaster's, [*The Unreasonable Utility of Recreational Mathematics*](http://anduin.eldar.org/~problemi/singmast/ecmutil.html) is a good read and it provides many examples of recreational mathematics which became useful decades, centuries, or more after they were proposed as intellectual exercises.

A planned awkwardness can make an idea more memorable.  A famous thought experiment is [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat), which fits your definition:

> some prepared, working awkwardness, that is worth to show because it does work and/or is interesting, and even maybe solves some problems.

But "awkwardness" is often not inherent, but rather just "different than what we normally think or experience".  All new ideas, new scientific models, new mathematical models, etc. go through a stage of being awkward, weird, or counter-intuitive. The expression of a new way of looking at things can be part of problem solving, model creation or paradigm shifting.  All of these can be enjoyed for the problems they solve or simply for the mental stimulation itself.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a [curiosity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curiosity?searchDictCode=all)

> An unusual or interesting object or fact

Comment: Also maybe 'oddity'